# clickable button over image/icon in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, button, vuetify.js, imagebutton

how could I made button with  this UI

[`<v-btn><v-img>...<v-img></v-btn>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hVe3.png)

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information here to provide a definitive answer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You may look into [HTML Links](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

HTML links are hyperlinks.
You can click on a link and jump to another document.
When you move the mouse over a link, the mouse arrow will turn into a little hand.

Therefore, your code should be

```
<a href="#"><v-img>...</v-img></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

go through [this](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/rNJpOzJ?editors=101) let me know if still, you face any problems.

Here is the code :-

```
        <v-btn icon @click="btnClicked">
          <v-img
            src="https://picsum.photos/510/300?random"
            aspect-ratio="1.7"
          ></v-img>
          </v-btn>
```